# TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python-2.7, graphml, pygraph

I am trying to parse a GraphMl file  with the following [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZklc.png)

And i am getting the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADQGb.png).

Would you please help me in solving this?

Answer (score 0):

Note: it's the first time that I encounter *pygraphml*.

The problem seems to be a logical error in your graph definition file (*test.graphml*). On top of that [*pygraphml2.0*](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygraphml/2.0), doesn't seem to handle well such errors:

As pointed out, the error: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment`, comes from *graphml_parser.py* line *114*:

```
e[attr.getAttribute("key")] = attr.firstChild.data
```

`e` is/*should be* an object of type `pygraphml.edge.Edge`, and is initialized in the same file at line *110*:

```
e = g.add_edge_by_label(source, dest)
```

the problem is that `e` is `None`, and hence the error. `g` (that instantiates `e`) is an object of type `pygraphml.graph.Graph`. Going to *graph.py*, `add_edge_by_label` is defined at line *147*:

```
def add_edge_by_label(self, label1, label2):
    """
    """

    n1 = None
    n2 = None

    for n in self._nodes:
        if n['label'] == label1:
            n1 = n
        if n['label'] == label2:
            n2 = n

    if n1 and n2:
        return self.add_edge(n1, n2)
    else:
        return
```

So, you're hitting the last `return` statement, meaning that in *test.graphml* you have (at least) one edge that has one label (or maybe both), that doesn't belong to any of the graph's nodes.

Obviously there's a problem (I consider it a bug) with *pygraphml*, if `Graph.add_edge_by_label` can return `None`, the `None` test should be performed `GraphMLParser.parse` (possibly elsewhere as well).

HTH (if it doesn't, you could send me the graph file to have a look at it).